# How to expose Dart functions to a scripting language in a Dart program (or Flutter application)

Tags: flutter, dart

My current work involves to create a Flutter application that must be scriptable from another language.
The application will provide a code editor, allowing users to write in a scripting language (it could be Ruby, Lua, Python...).
Some Dart functions of the application must be exposed to the scripting language, so the user can call those Dart functions from the scripting API provided.

I saw Starflut allows to call functions of a scripting language from Dart. But is there a way to call Dart exposed functions from the scripting language ?

It would also be great to be able to do that in pure Dart (calling Dart exposed functions from Dart script), which I'm not sure would be possible with AOT. Any idea?

I should add that my project targets desktop platforms.